# The meaning of "to be a matter of"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

> Happiness **is a matter of** health in body and soul.

The sentence is meant to say that "happiness is defined by health in body and soul".

Does "is a matter of" mean that? Is it idiomatic to use it in that sense? Or any better phrase to use instead of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the sentence mean what it is meant to mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/213175/does-the-sentence-mean-what-it-is-meant-to-mean)

Comment: @JasonBassford That is a different question.

Comment: @Sasan: please explain us how they are different.

Comment: @virolino - One question asks about "is a matter of". The other question asks about "is about". Perhaps you could explain how those are duplicates?

Comment: @virolino They are two different question about two different phrases that may or may not mean the same thing. Isn't it obvious?

Comment: @J.R.: As explained by the OP, both sentences have the same meaning. They are variants of saying pretty much the same thing. Both questions should have been written as one, eventually. Maybe asking "What is the difference in meaning". Also, "is a matter of" was discussed already in the comments of the other question.

Comment: @virolino I said two *phrases* not two *sentences*. And I didn't say "both have the same meaning", I said they "*may or may not* mean the same thing". But even if they had the same meaning, they still could be different questions.

Comment: @virolino - The OP has not "explained" that both sentences mean the same thing. The OP has asked about the meaning of two different phrases in two different questions.